# Correct usage of JSON Web Tokens

Tags: authentication, authorization, jwt

The question more focuses on the correct usage of JWT, after clarifying few thoughts.

Let's talk about only encoded (not encrypted) JWTs, and let's consider only `HMAC` which uses a symmetric secret key, let's call this `p@$$w0rd` which will be used to sign the JWT.

***We know that JWTs should not contain sensitive information as they do not hide any data as payload is only Base64 encoded, they are only supposed to verify through the `signature` that information is coming from correct client.***

In our case we are sending `role` for the purpose of showing/hiding certain elements from our Web application.
As in a user with `admin` role will see links to create/modify/delete users, etc as an example.

**Scenario**

`A` -> an `admin` user, requests JWT from Server (issuer) upon Login

`Server` -> Issues JWT with claims of `userID`, `userName`, `role` and with an expiration date.

`A` -> supposed to send this JWT token upon all further API requests to the `server` and server will use this token to authenticate.

`B` -> is a non-admin user and follows same procedure.

*`B` knows that `A` is an admin user and knows it's `userID` and `userName` as well. This is very likely possible, nowhere there is sensitive information.*

JWT only has claims Base64 encoded and if the client knows the `secret p@$$w0rd` as well, the token can be easily generated by the client. As we know the verifier `server` only re-hashes the encoded JWT (coming from client) to match the one it sent *`upon login`* using the secret.

*Through `https` we can be sure that 3rd party or man in the middle has no way to know this secret or any other information, so let's leave that aside.*

**#1**

`B` being a malicious user modifies it's own token and changes the role to that of `admin` and makes an API call only permissible to admin users.

`Server` can easily invalidate this token as the re-hashing will fail because the original token issued to `B` was modified and when we modify the token the signature also changes as it's made up of payload as well.

**#2**

`B` being a malicious user creates a token to match that of `A` with all of `A`s details and makes an API request only permissible to admin users.

The `server` will successfully verify that token and come to know that it's `A`.

**How to prevent this?**

- Should we use an `id` claim as part of payload that is unique and
  cannot be easily guessed?    Due to this `B` cannot derive the
  correct set of claims to create the exact `A`s token.    Although
  this approach is a bit more involved in storing this extra ID for
  every user and authenticating at server.
- Should we never disclose the `secret` key used to sign the JWT, so
  the client can ever create the token?

We know that JWTs are certainly a better way to authenticate as compared to `Basic Authorization` which sends the user's Base64 encoded `password` as well in every API request which has a much larger attack window.

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 - If using symmetric keys never, ever disclose them to the client if the client is unsecured in any way, particularly if the client is a web application.  It's a good idea to just not ever give out the symmetric keys.  JWTs should be manufactured on a/the server i.e pre-signed with the symmetric key and then given to the client.  The client can ask for a JWT by means of a secured API via some form of authentication, or you can create the JWT and dole out to a client by other means.

We do both.  Domain users that are already authenticated can request an expiring JWT via an API call.  User's outside of the domain are delivered a JWT specifically for them by an approved adminstrator on the domain that can access the API call.  At no time is the symmetric key(s) exposed.

This process starts to duplicate some aspects of OAuth, so you might want to investigate OAuth servers/vendors, which is where we are going.

Comment: Don't disagree with your points @programmerj, I wouldn't disclose a symmetric key to clients either. On the other hand usage of Asymmetric keys will be more expensive than Symmetric, as the verification process will take longer and as this happens for every API request, can cause performance issues.
But what if we used a non-guessable unique `id` as a claim with the token so it can't be easily generated by someone?

Comment: I suppose I am not fully understanding your concern.  If the symmetric key is never given out, then even if someone duplicates a user's JWT header and payload, they can't generate a signature, so the JWT will never be validated by the server.  If someone steals the whole valid JWT, then the expiration claim should take care of that.  Using a "non-guessable unique id" is essentially "security by obscurity" and is generally not a good idea.  The scenarios you mention have been addressed by security experts, so I again point you to OAuth or other industry standards for an answer.

Comment: Using OAuth is a bit more involved than using JWTs, and they are easier to setup and get going. I don't believe for a mid sized project there is much harm in using them.

Comment: You can use JWTs as your authorization token without OAuth; I am doing that right now.  OAuth just dictates the process for acquiring/managing the JWTs.  And the size of the project doesn't matter; its the scope of the exposure and the ramifications of a compromise.